# cloudfront - lambda function - s3 encryption with KMS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-kms

I am trying to implement this

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/serving-sse-kms-encrypted-content-from-s3-using-cloudfront/

I have a 503 error

```
The Lambda function associated with the CloudFront distribution is invalid or doesn't have the required permissions. We can't connect to the server for this app or website at this time. There might be too much traffic or a configuration error. Try again later, or contact the app or website owner.

If you provide content to customers through CloudFront, you can find steps to troubleshoot and help prevent this error by reviewing the CloudFront documentation.
```

Do you know what could be the issue. May I need to replace the variables?

```
accessKeyId: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, 
secretAccessKey: AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
sessionToken: AWS_SESSION_TOKE
```

What is the best practice to have s3 encrypted and working with cloudfront? is this the only option? Also, I think that cloudfront do not have encrypted the cache right? so not sure that this should be a good solution. anyone have any thought or dealing with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might have to check the permissions that your lambda function needs in order to run as a lambda-at-edge. You can have a look [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-edge-permissions.html#lambda-edge-permissions-function-execution) for more information and/or have a look at the default policies provided by AWS IAM for a policy that includes default permissions for running lambda functions at the edge.

Comment: I have a role AWSLambdaEdgeExecutionRole-f9ccefa4-3223-48a9-a4f5-0e5e34d2e69f as the link said and also full access to s3. Also I see in the function that it has replicator.lambda.GetFunction. If the buket is on diferent az mine is in US West (N. California) us-west-1. could be an issue?

Comment: I also see the service roles created